# matching partial name in direcotry

Tags: python, file, pdf, operating-system

**Problem Description**

I have two folders `list_input_files` and `list_out_files`

> input folder contains the names of scanned pdf files and 
>   output folder contains the names of pictures extracted from each pdf. File name is just same as file name in `list_input_folder` but additionally having the extension of page numbers like`Page_no1.jpg, Page_no2.jpg and so on ...`

**This is how folder and files look like**

`list_input_folder= ['file_a.pdf', 'file_b.pdf', 'file_c.pdf']`

`list_out_folder=['file_a.page_no1.png', file_a.page_no2.png',file_a.page_no3.png', file_b.page_no1.png'
file_b.page_no2.png,file_c.page_no1.png]`

**This is the code to extract the image from pdfs**

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
import os
input_file='file_a.pdf'
in_path=os.path.join(r"C:\Users\fkhalil\primeStone\docrecog\sampleDocs",input_file)
out_path=os.path.join(r"C:\Users\fkhalil\primeStone\docrecog\sampleDocs\convertedPdfs",input_file)
from wand.image import Image as wi
pdf = wi(filename=in_path, resolution=300)
pdfimage = pdf.convert("jpeg")
i = 1
for img in pdfimage.sequence:
     save_pages = 'Page_no' + str(i) + ".jpg"
     page = wi(image=img)
     page.save(filename=out_path+save_pages)
     i +=1
```

**What I want to do?**

I want to write program to make sure that if pdf is already being converted system raise the `file has already been converted`and go to the next file and start it converting and so on. to avoid the time and resources waste on work already done.

**What I have tried**

```py
o=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\fkhalil\primeStone\docrecog\sampleDocs\convertedPdfs")
o=[opt.split()[:-1] for opt in o] # to get rid on the page_no.. and the compare the file
# o=[''.join(o) for o in o]
# o=list(set(o))
print(o)
i=input_file.split() 
print(i[:-2])
# o=output.replace('out_','')
if i[:-1]==o:
    print('file already exit')
else:
    print('next block of code')
```

I shall be grateful for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_input_folder= ['file_a.pdf', 'file_b.pdf', 'file_c.pdf','file_d.pdf']
list_out_folder=['file_a.page_no1.png', 'file_a.page_no2.png','file_a.page_no3.png', 'file_b.page_no1.png','file_b.page_no2.png','file_c.page_no1.png']

processed_files = [fi.split('.')[0]+'.pdf' for fi in list_out_folder]
for i in list_input_folder:
    if i in processed_files:
        print("files exist")
    else:
        print('process file')
```

lets suppose you get list of files in input folder and output folder , then you can try above solution , this will print process file for 'file_d.pdf' only

Answer (score 1):

I have modified you code to make it work. Try this -

```
allFilesInDir=os.listdir(r"C:\Users\fkhalil\primeStone\docrecog\sampleDocs\convertedPdfs")
# o=[opt.split()[:-1] for opt in o]  to get rid on the page_no.. and the compare the file
processedPDF = []

for item in allFilesInDir:
    filename = item.split(".")[0]
    if filename not in processedPDF:
        processedPDF.append(filename)

print(filename)

i=input_file.split(".")[0] 
print i

# o=output.replace('out_','')
if i in processedPDF:
    print('File already Processed')
else:
    print('next block of code')
```

In the above code, I am going through all the files in `convertedPdfs` directory and creating a list of filenames that are processed.

After that when I get input filename I check if this name is present in `processedPDF` list.

Note : I am only taking out the first name from the file name before first `.`.